# Backbone menu refresh handling

Tags: button, backbone.js, refresh

I am using yeoman workflow http://yeoman.io/ , 
I have build a simple menu layout to handle the menu css :

```
var menu = new Backbone.Layout({
template: "layouts/menu",
className: "menu",
events: {
      'click a': 'changeActive'
     },
changeActive: function(e) {
$(e.target).parent().siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
$(e.target).parent().addClass('active');
...
```

It work fine but I am facing a problem in which I bump into very often,
when user clicks on browser's refresh button of course it doesn't remember the state and display 
the initial state. 
What is the best way to solve that ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You could save the last selected value to the cookie or to the localStorage and inside the `initialize` method make it active.
2. You can update the hash and save selected value there. On `initialize` just get it and make proper menu active.